# loading of many read table files in R

Tags: r

I have "manual" file loading. However, I have about 20 files. I try to read them using loops, but I have a lot of problems with that.

manual:

```
library(igraph)

graph<-read.table("R_test/1_1.txt")
network_name<- c(basename("R_test/1_1.txt"))
```

I tried using a csv loop, but "read.table" does not read this ...

```
setwd("/R_test/network")
ldf <- list() # creates a list
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.csv") 
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
  ldf[[k]] <- read.csv(listcsv[k])

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the length of the list to be able to assign to individual slots:

```
setwd("/R_test/network")
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.csv") 
ldf <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(listcsv)) # creates a list
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
  ldf[[k]] <- read.csv(listcsv[k])
}
```